# Problema de reconhecimento de variável passada do Laravel para o JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html, laravel

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web com Laravel e percebi algo estranho.

Ao passar uma variável do Laravel para a página HTML está acontecendo dois comportamentos diferentes:

- ao chamar a variável em um script interno no HTML a mesma é reconhecida;
- porém, ao chamar a variável em um script externo, em um arquivo JavaScript referenciando-o no final da tag body do HTML, a mesma não é reconhecida.

Esclareço que fiz teste tanto com o echo do Blade do Laravel, quanto com o as tags de abertura e fechamento do php no arquivo JavaScript e a variável não foi reconhecida.

Alguém sabe porque acontece esse tipo de comportamento?

Abaixo informo uma amostra do código usado no Laravel:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=pt-br>

<head>
 <meta charset="utf=8">
 <title>Teste</title>

</head>

<body>

<div>
<img class="destaque1" src="{{ asset('images/banners/00004.jpg') }}">
</div>

<script>
var stringImagensBanners = "{{ $imagensBanners }}";
var banners = stringImagensBanners.split(",");
var bannerAtual = 0;

function trocaBanner() {
 document.querySelector('.destaque1').src = banners[bannerAtual];
 bannerAtual = (bannerAtual + 1);

 if (bannerAtual == 5) {
 bannerAtual = 0;
 } return false;
}

setInterval(trocaBanner, 4000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: pode postar o codigo que envia e o script que recebe a variavel ?

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Por favor, se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Se eu entendi, isso que você tá tentando fazer não é possível, pois você está tentando interpretar um comando php dentro de um arquivo .js, para que o php seja interpretado ele precisa estar dentro de um arquivo .php. O que você poderia fazer é colocar colocar essa informação dentro de um input hidden e depois pegar no js externo com um seletor tipo: `$('#id-input-hidden').val();`

Comment: Obrigado pela orientação JuniorNunes.

Comment: não sei se entendi, mas vc quer usar uma variavel php dentro de um arquivo js referenciado na pagina?

Comment: Tava tentando fazer assim porque vi em outros foruns algo parecido e pensei que funcionava.
Então, não tem como usar REST do PHP no JavaScript direto, tem que ser intermediado pelo html?
Já vi alguns vídeos tutoriais usando template Blade no arquivo .js e estava querendo esclarecer essa questão.

Comment: Sim Douglas é isso.

Answer (score 1):

Já tive o mesmo problema desenvolvendo com Laravel 5, e a solução que encontrei foi usar `<?=  ?>` ou `<?php echo "";  ?>` concatenado com o JS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=pt-br>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf=8">
    <title>Teste</title>

</head>

<body>

<div>
    <img class="destaque1" src="{{ asset('images/banners/00004.jpg') }}">
</div>

<script>
var stringImagensBanners = "<?= $imagensBanners ?>";
var banners = stringImagensBanners.split(",");
var bannerAtual = 0;

function trocaBanner() {
    document.querySelector('.destaque1').src = banners[bannerAtual];
    bannerAtual = (bannerAtual + 1);

    if (bannerAtual == 5) {
    bannerAtual = 0;
    } return false;
}

setInterval(trocaBanner, 4000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```